# Cast int to enum in Python for my program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, casting, enums

How can a `int` be cast to an `enum` in python?

Comment: there are no enums in stdlib on Python 2. Or do you mean you have C code that accept a enum and you want to call from Python?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well, that would be the case in some situations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the flexibility to convert between `int` and an enum, you can use [`enum.IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum)

```
import enum

class Color(enum.IntEnum):
    green = 1
    blue = 2
    red = 3
    yellow = 4

color_code = 4
# cast to enum
color = Color(color_code)

# cast back to int
color_code = int(color)
```

*Note: If you are using python<3.4, `enum` has been backported, but you will need to install it, e.g. via `pip install enum`*

More on enums in python - https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `Enum` (Python 3.4+), the [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)  backport, or, for more advanced needs (which this is not), the new [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library.

If you use `IntEnum`:

```
class RGB(IntEnum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

If you have an `int` and want the matching `Enum` member:

```
>>> c = 2
>>> c = RGB(c)
>>> c
<RGB.green: 2>
```

Once you have an `IntEnum` member, it is already an `int`:

```
>>> type(c)
<enum 'RGB'>
>>> isinstance(c, int)
True
```

The downside to `IntEnum` is that every `IntEnum` member will compare equal to every other `IntEnum` member that has the same value:

```
class Fruit(IntEnum):
    banana = 1

>>> Fruit.banana == Color.red
True
```

If you want to keep your `Enum`s separate, but don't want to lose the `int`ability of an `IntEnum` you could do:

```
class RGB(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
```

Lookup works the same:

```
>>> c = 2
>>> c = RGB(c)
>>> c
<RGB.green: 2>
```

But members are no longer `int`s:

```
>>> type(c)
<enum 'RGB'>
>>> isinstance(c, int)
False
```

So you do have to cast it (or access the `value` attribute):

```
>>> int(c)
2
>>> c.value
2
```

And we no longer have the problem if `Fruit.banana` being equal to `RGB.red`:

```
>>> Fruit(1) == RGB(1)
False
```

---

If you are using Python 3+ there are some cool things you can do with `aenum`, such as:

```
import aenum

class RGB(aenum.Enum, start=1):
    red
    green
    blue
    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
```

which results in the same class as the last `Enum` example.

Answer (score 0):

For here latest `Python 3.7` and some Enum:

```py
from enum import Enum

class BatteryState(Enum):
    Unknown = 0
    Unplugged = 1
    Charging = 2
    Full = 3
```

## Convert Int to Enum

just pass **int** to `Enum`

```py
batteryStateInt = 2
curBattryState = BatteryState(batteryStateInt)
print("curBattryState=%s" % curBattryState)
```

can got what you expected `Enum`:

```
curBattryState=BatteryState.Charging
```

## Extra

get Enum string expression can via `name`

```py
curBattryStateName = curBattryState.name
print("curBattryStateName=%s" % curBattryStateName)
```

can got expected: `Charging`